# Nested case statements in SML

Tags: sml

This is more of a stylistic question than anything else. Given the following piece of code:

```
case e1 of                    (* datatype type_of_e1  = p1 | p2 *)
    p1 => case e11 of         (* datatype type_of_e11 = NONE | SOME int *)
              NONE => expr11
            | SOME v => expr12 v
  | p2 => case e21 of         (* datatype type_of_e21 = NONE | SOME string *)
              NONE => expr21
            | SOME v => expr22 v
```

Is there a way to resolve the `types of rules don't agree` error caused by trying to pattern match *e11* to *p2*, other than enclosing *p1*'s expression in parenthesis? The *p2* pattern has another case statement, to avoid the *'just switch the patterns'* answer ;-).

**update:** changed the code to reflect a more concrete case

Comment: What is `e2`? Can you provide a complete function? It is an **error**, so it's better to fix it before worrying about coding style.

Comment: @pad: I've updated the code to clear up the confusion. `e2` was the initial name of `e11`, Having changed the code to add a case for `p2` I've forgot the change it's name in the question. The only error I get is if I don't surround in parenthesis the expression for `p1`.

Comment: Speaking of coding style, it is good style to have value constructors starting with a capital letter, to avoid any confusion of it being a varaible. Here I', talking about your `p1` and `p2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The syntactic rules in the Definition of Standard ML state that the match arms of a case expression attempt to maximally consume potential clauses. And since there's no "end case" or similar marker in the language, the parser will merrily eat each of the "| pat => exp" clauses that you feed it until it sees something that terminates a list of match clauses.

Comment: Sorry, I was to vague with my code, I've updated it since. My confusion arises from the fact that the `case` expression does consume all of the potential clauses (`e11` being an `option`, `NONE` and `SOME v` will cover all cases, leaving the parser with no option other than ending the `case` expression).

Comment: @slash3r The parser does not know about types. Type checking phase comes-in after the parser is done constructing AST.

Answer (score 19):

The answer is "(" and ")". For example:

```
case e1 of                   
   p1 => ( case e11 of         
              NONE => expr11
              | SOME v => expr12 v )
   | p2 => ( case e21 of         
                NONE => expr21
                | SOME v => expr22 v )
```

Let me know if it works for you too

Answer (score 4):

Plain and short answer: no. But what's wrong with parentheses?

(Of course, you can also bracket in other ways, e.g. with a 'let', or by factoring into auxiliary functions, but parentheses are the canonical solution.)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with them, I was just hopping that I missed a more elegant work around for this problem.