# SML: multiple case statements

Tags: sml

How can I have multiple case statements which do not interleave with each other.
A toy example for instance:

```
 fun multi_cases(xs) =
     case xs of
       [] => 5
      | x::ys => case x of
                    1 => 2
                   |_ => 3
      | x::[] => case x of
                    1 => 5
                    | _ => 7
 ;

stdIn:59.17-64.28 Error: types of rules don't agree [overload conflict]
  earlier rule(s): [int ty] -> [int ty]
  this rule: [int ty] list -> [int ty]
  in rule:
    :: (x,nil) =>
      (case x
        of 1 => 5
         | _ => 7)
```

The last two case statements are getting mixed up how can I tell SML that they are indeed two independent case statements rather than a continuation/separate branch of case x of 1 => 2 ...

The patterns above as pointed in the answer below have an issue with their generality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested case statements in SML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708732/nested-case-statements-in-sml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has two distinct problems:

1. As the question [Nested case statements in SML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708732/nested-case-statements-in-sml) that John links to says, *case-of*s are a little tricky syntactically because their list of case statements never "stops". That is, your code actually gets parsed as:

   ```
   fun multi_cases xs =
       case xs of
            [] => 5
          | x::ys => case x of
                          1 => 2
                        | _ => 3
                        | x::[] => case x of
                                        1 => 5
                                      | _ => 7
   ```

   which is nonsensical because that third pattern should have belonged to the outer *case-of* and not the inner (the inner *case-of* deals with `x` as an *int*, and the outer with `x::[]` as an *int list*).

   Since your indentation does not actively help the compiler towards the intended meaning, using parentheses to "stop" the *case-of*s from intertwining, like that post says, is the fix:

   ```
   fun multi_cases xs =
       case xs of
            [] => 5
          | x::ys => (case x of
                          1 => 2
                        | _ => 3)
          | x::[] => (case x of
                           1 => 5
                         | _ => 7)
   ```

   Alternatively you could turn the outer *case-of* into a match on the function's arguments itself and blend the inner *case-of* together with it, since a single pattern match allows for arbitrarily deep matching:

   ```
   fun fun_cases [] = 5
     | fun_cases [1] = 5
     | fun_cases [_] = 7
     | fun_cases (1::_) = 2
     | fun_cases (_::_) = 3
   ```
2. Your two cases overlap because `x::xs` is a more general pattern than `x::[]`. That is, it also covers the list `x::[]` by setting `xs` to `[]`. You could fix that in one of two ways:

   1. List the least general pattern first, e.g.

      ```
      case xs of
           [] => 5
         | [x] => ...
         | x::_ => ...
      ```
   2. Make that `x::xs` general pattern into a less general one by specifying that the list should have at least two elements:

      ```
      case xs of
           x :: _ :: _ => ...
         | [x] => ...
         | [] => ...
      ```

Comment: What do these brackets do? Do they add in some kind of pattern matching?

Comment: +1 question, is there a rule in the language which would help you define the more general patterns first? As the less general patterns would not match.

Comment: What brackets? I'm not sure what you mean by rules in the language. Stack Overflow isn't really suitable for forth-and-back discussion in the commentary, or for continuous elaboration on sub-questions. I'd recommend you read an [entry-level book on Standard ML](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Programming-International-Computer-Science/dp/0201398206), take a course that has TAs, or read about specific subjects, such as [type inference/unification](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2005sp/lectures/lec22.asp).